# Should I use a Graph library?

Tags: c++, c, graph, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I am making a DFS and BFS solver for a maze.

I have no knowledge (pretty much abysmal knowledge) of how to implement a Graph in C++ and how to implement the nodes which will have multiple children depending on how many adjacent cells are empty.

I have been searching for days on a beginner friendly way to implement a graph in C++. Literally. Days.

Everything I've found was too complicated for me, I only found advanced stuff that I could not understand. The most beginner friendly site I've found is [this](http://www.programming-techniques.com/2012/07/depth-first-search-in-c-algorithm-and.html) but in this one it is using C and it's even implementing the stack which I believe in C++ there already is a Stack class. Even this site I have trouble understanding.

My problem with using an already made library is that I will never learn how to actually implement a graph and the nodes and I think that will greatly hurt my knowledge on the subject.

I am downloading the boost library as I type this, so if I decide to use a library I will use this one probably.

So should I never learn how to create graphs and nodes and just use the boost library (or any other for that matter) or are there actual beginner friendly ways to learn how to construct graphs and nodes for a DFS algorithm and especially for a maze?

Comment: When I had this homework in my CS curriculum, I solved it without a graph library... so I think the answer to your question is: no.

Comment: Did you find "a beginner friendly way to implement a graph" in any other language? Which one?

Comment: @sehe I only searched in C, C++ and Java since they are the three languages I can understand. I could only find pseudo-code for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since DFS and BFS are trivial algorithms, there isn't any need to get them from a library. Yes, they are implemented in [BGL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) but this library is primarily for more complicated algorithms. Also, BGL does provide some graph representations but is actually implemented in a way where you can use your own graph data structure and still apply BGL's algorithms. But differently: implement the graph and the algorithms yourself!

For DFS and BFS implementing a graph is fairly straight forward as you don't even need a separate edge type (there is no additional data stored for edges beyond where they point to). To implement a graph you'll need a *node* type which stores a flag (to indicate if the node was visited) and a container with indicators of the target nodes. Most often, the container just stores pointers to the target node which, of course, means that the nodes pointed to stay put in memory.

You could use either a `std::deque<Node>` if you only add/remove nodes at one of the ends or a `std::list<Node>` if you may add/remove nodes anywhere in the graph (for implementing DFS and BFS you only add nodes which can be done at the end, i.e., I'd go with `std::deque<Node>`). Internally in the nodes you'd just store a `std::vector<Node*>`. When inserting an edge between two nodes you just find the two nodes and add a pointer to source node's `std::vector<Node*>` to the target `Node`. If the graph is undirected, you'd add pointers to the `std::vector<Node*>` of both nodes.

BTW, I wouldn't call DFS or BFS "artificial intelligence". Also, it seems you are looking for a C++ solution, i.e., the C tag seems misplaced, too.

Comment: My main problem is how to represent the children that each node will have. Is that what you mean with the vector<Node*> ? So basically I will have a node struct which will have as properties: int row; int column; bool visited; vector<Node*>; right?

Comment: @SiliconTouch: in a graph you don't really have _children_ but you have _adjacent nodes_. However, yes, the list of adjacent nodes is what is stored in the `Node`s `std::vector<Node*>`. What else is stored in each node depends on the needs of the application.

Comment: Just to chime in: I generally like to make the whole graph "just" a vector of vertices (i.e. adjacency-list) - and by ordering them on either source or destination it becomes a "flat-(multi)-map" so you can do very efficient std::lower_bound/std::upper_bound lookups on them

Comment: @DietmarKühl It seems to me that just using a vector to connect the nodes together is as simple as it can get. Also I have already made the node struct which for now at least contains the row, the column, the visited state and the vector<node*> array. I guess that's a good place to start at but I will look at this again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have to implement a Node as a complex structure.
In the case node represents just a cell of a maze you can use integer numbers to identify the particular cell.

In the case maze is MxN size you will have an array of nodes MxN lenght.

To represents adjacency relation between nodes you can use adjacency matrix (which is ok in case of small enough graphs) or adjacency lists (which is more efficient in your case because each node can have 4 or less adjacent nodes).

You can easily search about adjacency representation in Google.

So, this is the case you really need nothing complex to impelement these algorithms.
You will only need arrays (but it's really better to use vector container from STL) and queue container from STL for BFS (DFS uses stack but you can use recursion which uses stack explicitly).